# Finding consecutive characters but ignore space & case?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to match the following strings so that I can later truncate them from the string in JS.
For ex:
matched: i like **eee**ting pie and **a a a a a** bananas.
matched: My name **iII**s John Doe and **A a A a AA AAA** I'm cool.

This is the regex I currently have, but it doesn't match if there is a space in between or if there are more than 3 consecutive letters:

```
(.)\1\1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
/(\S)(?:\s*\1){2,}/gi
/\b(\S)(?:\s*\1){2,}/gi
```

If you need to make sure you only start matching at the word boundary, you need to use the second regex.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "i like eeeting pie and a a a a a bananas. My name iIIs John Doe and A a A a AA AAA I'm cool.";
const re = /(\S)(?:\s*\1){2,}/gi;
document.body.innerHTML = text.replace(re, '<b>$&</b>')
// Second regex demo:
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>" + text.replace(/\b(\S)(?:\s*\1){2,}/gi, '<b>$&</b>')
```

The regex has the `i` case insensitive flag and matches

- `(\S)` - Group 1: any non-whitespace char
- `(?:\s*\1){2,}` - two or more occurrences of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `\1` - the value of Group 1.

See the [regex scheme](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb(%5CS)(%3F%3A%5Cs*%5C1)%7B2%2C%7D):

[image]

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I've just added image of regex.

Comment: @HR01M8055, can you share the tool to create this image of regex?

Comment: @Jashwant I added a link in the answer.